# Magento Site blanks out every night

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

For some reason my Magento site blanks out every night. Every morning I have to clear cache through command line for it to come back up. Any ideas why?

Comment: What do you mean by "blanks out"?  What version of Magento are you on?

Comment: Check your space quota, may be this is space issue.

Comment: 1.6.2.0 it just blanks out, I get a white page in the morning. How can I check that?

Comment: check space from your hosting company, if it is not exceeded

Comment: But do you think that's the cause since just a quick cache clear fixes it until the next day?

Comment: Do you have tasks in crontab for night run?

Comment: How can I check that?

Comment: Please check your error logs, both magento and server error logs

Comment: Wow grim i remember having something like this in M1 where cache configs used to corrupt nothing like it in M2 ...yet